# Pydev No Hover Text for String arguments

Tags: python, eclipse-rcp, pydev

I'm building an RCP app that serves as an IDE for a custom domain. One of the things we do in that domain is write python scripts that use domain-specific commands which have been wrapped as python functions. I implemented hover text support integrated with PyDev, so that if there is any domain-specific hover text available, it calls a custom `ITextHover` instead of PyDev's.

I have this working, but I see that if I have a string literal argument to a function, the `getTextHover()` method is never called on the `IHoverText` instance. I traced this behavior to the partitioning implementation provided by `getConfiguredDocumentPartitioning` in `PyEditConfiguration`.

Is there a way I can use PyDev's partitioning scheme but somehow override the above behavior, so that `getTextHover()` is called for String literal arguments? I don't see anything in the preferences, and trying to follow the implementation in the PyDev source code was not successful.

EDIT: overriding `TextSourceViewerConfiguration#getConfiguredDocumentPartitioning()` to return `IPythonPartitions.PY_DEFAULT` solves the problem. But I'm not sure what the implications are of returning this rather than `IPythonPartitions.PYTHON_PARTITION_TYPE`, which is the behavior provided by `PyEditCOnfigurationWithoutEditor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't change what you changed...

The proper way would be changing PyDev itself to support your use case.

You should provide your IPyHoverParticipant (instead of doing your own text hover) and create a pull request for PyDev so that the hover works in comments/strings (i.e.: skip the "if (!pythonCommentOrMultiline) {" in org.python.pydev.editor.hover.PyTextHover.getHoverInfo(ITextViewer, IRegion) if your hover implements IPyHoverParticipant2).

Comment: Where can I find IPyHoverParticipant2? I only have IPyHoverParticipant in my PyDev codebase. I checked out source from https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev.git and tried various branches.

Comment: I made a contribution to pydev_completion extension point, and that takes a IPyDevCompletionParticipant2 implementation. (Actually the ext point documentation called for IPyDevCompletionParticipant, but a runtime error said to use IPyDevCompletionParticipant2). Maybe you were thinking of that when you said IPyHoverParticipant2?

Comment: The problem with no TextHover for String args went away when I used the hover participant instead of the hack I was doing. So I don't think there's anything to fix in PyDev regarding this.

Comment: I meant that you should create an IPyHoverParticipant2 and contribute it to PyDev ;)

Comment: I see now. I thought you were saying to implement that interface. But you were saying to create it and use it as a marker, causing the "if (!pythonCommentOrMultiline)" check to be bypassed.

Comment: After upgrading to PyDev 4.5, hover info is not provided for Strings and comments. So I implemented your suggested change and created this pull request: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/pull/155.